# NURB Sphere surface degree elevation and knot insertion

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, graphics, digital-curve

The code for degree elevation of curves in The NURBS Book by Les Piegl and Wayne Tiller pages 206--209([The_NURBS_Book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-97385-7)) assumes the knot vector for the curve is given as:
$$(0,...,0,...,1,...,1)$$
where there are p+1 0's and p+1 1's and numbers greater than 0 and less than 1 are in between the last 0 and the first 1 of the knot vector, where p is the degree of the curve.
However, here is one example where that presents a different case:([The_NURBS_sphere](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02948971))

The knot vector in u direction is $$(0,0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1,1)$$ and the u-degree is 2, how would I degree elevate the NURBS curves for the u direction?

Comment: https://itc.ktu.lt/index.php/ITC/article/view/12382

Comment: I tried the code, but the DDE algorithm doesn't give the correct result in elevation for an unclamped knot.